# Change push notification message displayed on lockscreen when receiving new message from my iMessage extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, imessage, imessage-extension

We have developed an iMessage extension, and when we send a message through it the receiver have a push notification with the following text:

> 1 message Messages Extension Plugin

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea on how to change this displayed text into a custom text?

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by setting summaryText property of MSMessage

```
let message = MSMessage()
message.summaryText = "this is the alert text that show up "
```